# How to locate the file a code object come from?

Tags: python, inspect

I need to know where a code object comes from ; its module. So I (naively) tried :

```
os.path.abspath(code.co_filename)
```

But that may or may not work, (I think it's because abspath depends on cwd)

Any way to get the **full path** of a code object's module ?

EDIT :
The functions from the inspect module : getfile, getsourcefile, getmodule, get only the file name, not its path (same thing as co_filename). Maybe they use abspath.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? What output do you get from your example code, and what are you expecting?

Comment: @Shaw Chin : I get only the name of the file, and I need it's full path.

Comment: Strange. What kind of code object is it?

Comment: @Shaw Chin : How many kinds are there ?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the way the object was compiled. See http://bugs.python.org/issue1665

Comment: Sarcasm, great. I was simply wondering how you installed it and if it was a pre-compiled object.

Comment: @Shaw Chin : Thanks for pointing out issue1665, that helped.

Answer (score 3):

```
import inspect
print inspect.getfile(inspect)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `inspect.getsourcefile()` function is what you need, it returns the relative path to the file where the object's source can be found.

Comment: inspect.getsourcefile(os.path) returned me '/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py' (it seems the returned path is either relative or absolute depending on the context).

Comment: yes, it depends on the context (like abspath), and that's the problem, I couln't rely on it.

Comment: `os.path.realpath(inspect.getsourcefile(obj))` seems to do what you want

Comment: realpath seems to depend also on the context

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the module, try `module.__file__`.

```
>>> import xml
>>> xml.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PyXML-0.8.4-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/_xmlplus/__init__.pyc'
```

If you don't, something like this should work:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> thing = ET.Element('test')
>>> __import__(thing.__module__).__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PyXML-0.8.4-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/_xmlplus/__init__.pyc'
```

In this case, we are using the fact that import can be called on the string version of the module, which returns the actual module object, and then calling `__file__` on that.